# How to detect a delimiter in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, delimiter

I am curious if you have a string how would you detect the delimiter?

We know php can split a string up with explode() which requires a delimiter parameter.

But what about a method to detect the delimiter before sending it to explode function?

Right now I am just outputting the string to the user and they enter the delimiter. That's fine -- but I am looking for the application to pattern recognize for me.

Should I look to regular expressions for this type of pattern recognition in a string?

EDIT: I have failed to initially specify that there is a likely expected set of delimiters. Any delimiter that is probably used in a CSV. So technically anyone could use any character to delimit a CSV file but it is more probable to use one of the following characters: comma, semicolon, vertical bar and a space.

EDIT 2: Here is the workable solution I came up with for a "determined delimiter".

```
$get_images = "86236058.jpg 86236134.jpg 86236134.jpg";

    //Detection of delimiter of image filenames.
        $probable_delimiters = array(",", " ", "|", ";");

        $delimiter_count_array = array(); 

        foreach ($probable_delimiters as $probable_delimiter) {

            $probable_delimiter_count = substr_count($get_images, $probable_delimiter);
            $delimiter_count_array[$probable_delimiter] = $probable_delimiter_count;

        }

        $max_value = max($delimiter_count_array);
        $determined_delimiter_array = array_keys($delimiter_count_array, max($delimiter_count_array));

        while( $element = each( $determined_delimiter_array ) ){
        $determined_delimiter_count = $element['key'];
        $determined_delimiter = $element['value'];
        }

        $images = explode("{$determined_delimiter}", $get_images);
```

Comment: What does the delimiter look like?

Comment: I'm confused regarding the logic of letting the user specify the delimiter. What's the purpose of that? Why not just use any one of the commonly used delimiters and be done with it?

Comment: @Alex what you are asking for sounds pretty unrealistic if anything could be a delimiter. Pattern matching to detect delimiters is a non-trivial task

Comment: Anything you come up with following this spec is going to be O(n^c). Where n is the set of all possible delimiters and c is the string length. *Ugly*...

Comment: Well, you could build a heuristic system that tries to identify a delimiter from a list of probable delimiters (`,;/|` all come to mind).  Depending on the need, you could do count analysis on the number of times the character appears in the file (after all, a delimiter would appear at least a few times per line, I would think)...

Comment: @Alex can you provide more details please. Some input data and what possible delimiters you expect.

Comment: I have failed to specify that there is a likely expected set of delimiters. Any delimiter that is probably used in a CSV. So technically anyone could use any character to delimit a CSV file but it is more probable to use one of the following characters: comma, semicolon, and a space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Determine which delimiters you consider probable (like `,`, `;` and `|`) and for each search how often they occur in the string (`substr_count`). Then choose the one with most occurrences as the delimiter and `explode`.

Even though that might not be fail-safe it should work in most cases ;)

Comment: This is bound to fail too often. What if I have content that contains heaps of `,,,,, ;;;;; ||||||`?

Comment: If it's for experimental purposes, it can be a start. Otherwise such constructs are going to be your systems downfall.

Comment: One option, is if the counts are high for more than one, or they are close together, go line by line through the file and count occurrences.  The one with the most stable number (differing by at most 1) is likely the delimiter...

Comment: @Pekka: Everything depend on the data expected to be entered. For example if you should input tags it is pretty improbably that a tagname will contain a `,` or a `;`.

Comment: I do think that this is the best attempt at doing this so far.

Comment: What if I choose `;` as the delimiter, but enter a string like: `Barbados,Belarus,Brazil;Canada,China,Congo,Cuba`? There's only one instance of the actual delimiter `;` but five instances of `,` which is another likely choice. In this case, choosing the one with the most occurrences will give the wrong result.

Comment: @stevelove You've got a point. That throws off this approach slightly.

Comment: @stevelove: Well, I already said, it depend on the expected data. If this is the kind of data you expect, then this is the wrong approach for sure.

Comment: @stevelove: For any system like this you can generate a delimited string/file that will lead to the wrong choice (hence why this is a heuristic, it *tends* to lead you to the correct answer, but not directly).  But that doesn't mean that it's bad to build just because there exist edge cases (which may not occur at all, depending on the use case)...

Answer (score 3):

I would say this works 99.99% of the cases :)
The basic idea is, that number of valid delimiters should be the same line by line.
This script calculates delimiter count discrepancies between all lines.
Less discrepancy means more likely valid delimiter.

Putting it all together this function read rows and return it back as an array:

```
function readCSV($fileName)
{
    //detect these delimeters
    $delA = array(";", ",", "|", "\t");
    $linesA = array();
    $resultA = array();

    $maxLines = 20; //maximum lines to parse for detection, this can be higher for more precision
    $lines = count(file($fileName));
    if ($lines < $maxLines) {//if lines are less than the given maximum
        $maxLines = $lines;
    }

    //load lines
    foreach ($delA as $key => $del) {
        $rowNum = 0;
        if (($handle = fopen($fileName, "r")) !== false) {
            $linesA[$key] = array();
            while ((($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $del)) !== false) && ($rowNum < $maxLines)) {
                $linesA[$key][] = count($data);
                $rowNum++;
            }

            fclose($handle);
        }
    }

    //count rows delimiter number discrepancy from each other
    foreach ($delA as $key => $del) {
        echo 'try for key=' . $key . ' delimeter=' . $del;
        $discr = 0;
        foreach ($linesA[$key] as $actNum) {
            if ($actNum == 1) {
                $resultA[$key] = 65535; //there is only one column with this delimeter in this line, so this is not our delimiter, set this discrepancy to high
                break;
            }

            foreach ($linesA[$key] as $actNum2) {
                $discr += abs($actNum - $actNum2);
            }

            //if its the real delimeter this result should the nearest to 0
            //because in the ideal (errorless) case all lines have same column number
            $resultA[$key] = $discr;
        }
    }

    var_dump($resultA);

    //select the discrepancy nearest to 0, this would be our delimiter
    $delRes = 65535;
    foreach ($resultA as $key => $res) {
        if ($res < $delRes) {
            $delRes = $res;
            $delKey = $key;
        }
    }

    $delimeter = $delA[$delKey];

    echo '$delimeter=' . $delimeter;

    //get rows
    $row = 0;
    $rowsA = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($fileName, "r")) !== false) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimeter)) !== false) {
            $rowsA[$row] = Array();
            $num = count($data);
            for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                $rowsA[$row][] = trim($data[$c]);
            }
            $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    return $rowsA;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I am dealing with a lot of CSV's from various databases, which various people extract to CSV in various ways, sometimes different each time for the same dataset ... Have simply implemented a function like this in my convert base class

```
protected function detectDelimiter() {
    $handle = @fopen($this->CSVFile, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $line=fgets($handle, 4096);
        fclose($handle);            

        $test=explode(',', $line);
        if (count($test)>1) return ',';

        $test=explode(';', $line);
        if (count($test)>1) return ';';

        //.. and so on
    }
    //return default delimiter
    return $this->delimiter;
}
```

Comment: this is not always good, for example:
test you brain, mate;okay;false;true
will fail..

Answer (score -2):

I made something like this:

```
$line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|");
if (isset($line[1]))
    {
    echo "delimiter is: |";
    $delimiter="|";
    }
    else
    {
    $line1 = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";");
    if (isset($line1[1]))
        {
        echo "delimiter is: ;";
        $delimiter=";";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "delimiter is: ,";
        $delimiter=",";
        }
    }
```

This simply checks whether there is a second column after a line is read.

Comment: You're approach could be interesting, but at least make it a loop ;)

Answer (score -2):

I am having the same issue. My system will recieve CSV files from the client but it could use ";", "," or " " as delimiter and I wnat to improve the system so the client dont have to know which is (They never do).

I search and found this library:
https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

Very good and easy to use.

Comment: This ill not work for a lot of reasons, what if, by luck, all number of delimiter ocurrences are the same? What is the only mathing ocurrence is zero? that means the entire line is a single column? Maybe you can search for CSV a library or plugin and use it

Comment: Yes, you are right. I use this library to solve my problem in the end: https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php